# No module named 'termios' when creating a DAG on Airflow Docker

Tags: python, docker, module, airflow, termios

I am trying to create a sample DAG on VSCode after installing Airflow through docker but I run into this error.

ModuleNotFoundError*: No module named 'termios'*

Wondering what went wrong with my installation? I installed a docker environment for this and all containers seem healthy. I am using Python 3.6.8 and AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.3

Kinda new to this whole thing and still figuring things out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what includes does your dag use?

Comment: Strange but it actually didn't create any include directory when I installed it through docker compose. I used this https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml

Comment: can you edit the post to include the code for the dag you are having problems with?